# Error in dispatching a mp3 file when bot entered in Voice Channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have install the latest node, ffmpeg and node-opus

```
if (msg.content === ('$join')) {
  if (msg.member.voiceChannel) {
          const connection = msg.member.voiceChannel.join();
          const dispather = connection.playFile('./birthday.mp3');
          dispatcher.on('end', () => connection.disconnect());
          .then(connection => {
              msg.reply('I have successfully connected to the channel!');
          });

  } else {
      msg.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
  }
}
```

When as myself join the voice channel and type '$join' it display "playFile" as not a function when it is in the documentation.

```
C:\ReinaBot\test2\app.js:40
          const dispather = connection.playFile('./birthday.mp3');
at Client.client.on.message (C:\ReinaBot\test2\app.js:40:44)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Client.emit (events.js:211:7)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\ReinaBot\test2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websock
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\ReinaBot\test2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\ReinaBot\test2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\ReinaBot\test2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\ReinaBot\test2\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

`voiceChannel.join()` doesn't return a connection. It returns a Promise.
From [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=playFile):

```
// Play files natively
voiceChannel.join()
  .then(connection => {
    const dispatcher = connection.playFile('C:/Users/Discord/Desktop/music.mp3');
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```